# german "umlauts"

Tags: html, parsing, internationalization, nokogiri

i have a problem with this code that i get the wrong html encoded german umlauts:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

time = Time.new

url = "http://mobile.bahn.de/bin/mobil/bhftafel.exe/dox?input=Richard-Strauss-Stra%DFe%2C+M%FCnchen%23625127&date=" + 
  time.strftime("%d%m%Y") +
  "&time=" +
  time.strftime("%H") +
  "%3A" +
  time.strftime("%M") +
  "&productsFilter=1111111111000000&REQTrain_name=&maxJourneys=10&start=Suchen&boardType=Abfahrt&ao=yes"

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
doc.xpath('//div//p').remove
doc.encoding = 'UTF-8'
doc = doc.xpath('//div').each do |node|
  text = node.text.gsub(/\n([ \t]*\n)+/,"\n",).gsub(/^\s+|\s+$/,'').gsub("Startseite", '').gsub("Impressum", '')
  puts text unless text.empty?
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by "get the wrong html encoded german umlauts"?  If you are displaying them in a terminal window, it's likely they are correct but the terminal doesn't recognize UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

The results of your code is perfect on my computer. All the Umlaute display correctly, not as HTML entities but as real Umlaute. Maybe check your Ruby version: Ruby 1.8 had problems with non-ASCII characters, Ruby 1.9 fixed that.